# Graphing percentage data in seaborn

Tags: python, graph, seaborn

How would I graph this data in seaborn. I would like to have the various categories on the x axis, and the data on the y axis as percentages.

I tried to create a barplot with seaborn but I can't get it to look right.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

[image]

Edit: code:

```
sns.barplot(x = new_df.columns,data=new_df)
```

Comment: show us the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you organize your DataFrame more like this, it will make it much easier to plot and organize this type of data.

Instead of doing your DataFrame as you have it, instead transpose it to two simple columns like so:

```
name                 value
debt_consolidation    0.152388
credit_card           0.115689
all_other             0.170111
```

etc. By doing this you can simply plot your data in Seaborn by doing the below:

```
sns.barplot(x="name",y="value", data = df)
```

[Which will look like this (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9QL0.png)

Comment: Perfect that's exactly what I want! But how do you set the first column's name. You have it as 'name'. How do I set that?

Comment: @user3594588 That would just be the name of your column. So when you define your DataFrame you define your column name with whatever you want to call it, name could be category, section, etc. Whatever you name it.

For example: 
`df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','values'])`

Comment: Edited my answer, for some reason I still can't get it to look like  yours

Comment: @user3594588 If you want to use what you call 'purpose' as the index in your Dataframe then you'd have to do something like this:

`l = ['debt_consolidation','credit_card','all_other']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data = [0.152388,0.115689,0.170111], index = l, columns = ['Values'])

sns.barplot(x=new_df.index, y='Values',data = new_df)`

Basically you need to use the index as the x value instead of some name.